# Denying access to files except if there is a specific querystring parameter defined

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file within a folder which contains subfolders. I have currently disabled the ability to directly access the .zip files within those subfolders, like this:

```
Options -Indexes
deny from all
<FilesMatch '\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|ogg)$'>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The thing is that I want to allow those .zip files to be accessed only if there is this `?access=allow` on the querystring.

I tried adding the following at the end of the file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(access=allow)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

It simply didn't work.

How shall I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule **as your very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(jpe?g|png|gif|mp3|ogg)[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)access=allow(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule \.zip$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I see, that seems to partially work, in fact it does, however I have the following declaration in my VirtualHost config file which is sending back a 403 if I access to _example.com/uploads/file.zip_: `RewriteRule /uploads/file.zip /real/path/to/uploads/file.zip?access=allow`

Comment: oh ok, in that case change first condition above to this: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/uploads/file\.zip[?\s]`

Comment: Oh no! The older code is what I was expecting and it was working perfectly with the exception that I wanted my VirtualHost config file to also address the `RewriteRule /uploads/file.zip /real/path/to/uploads/file.zip?access=allow` that was not working :( I was about to accept yours.

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. I rolled back my changes. Also, I don't see anything wrong in your `VirtualHost` rewrite rule.

Comment: As I said few comments back, it works, but partially because if I access to `example.com/uploads/somefile.zip` it throws back a 403. It seems that the `RewriteRules` you posted are not taking into consideration some `RewriteRules`included in my VirtualHost config file that states for example: `RewriteRule /uploads/somefile.zip /real/path/to/uploads/somefile.zip?access=allow`

Comment: I had made an update in the rule to address this particular case however you commented saying previous version was already working fine so I rolled back my change. Now I am confused. Did you test my 2nd version rules?

Answer (score 0):

To allow .zip files to accessed only if **access=allow** perameter is present in the querystring, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(access=allow)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule \.zip - [L]
```

and to disallow access to other extensions, add this rule :

```
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|gif|zip)$ - [F]
```

Comment: I rather prefer to keep the current code that contains the `FilesMatch`. Is there a way?

Comment: @Human With filesMatch directive you cant match against the querystring.

Comment: Hey! that didn't work, whether I type `mysite.com/my-file.zip?access=allow` or `mysite.com/my-file.zip` it access the file